# Change Language in QT StandardDialogs (QColorDialog)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, locale, qcolordialog

I've tried to change the Language of a QColorDialog from English to German but unfortunately it's not working. I am using PyQt.

What I've tried so far:

Setting the locale for the Dialog:

```
colordialog = QtWidgets.QColorDialog()
colordialog.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.German, QtCore.QLocale.Germany))
```

Installing a translator for the whole application:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
qt_translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
qt_translator.load("qt_" + QtCore.QLocale.system().name(),
QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
app.installTranslator(qt_translator)
```

Comment: What is the output of those last two commands? What OS are you using?

Comment: There is no Output. OS is Microsoft Windows.

Comment: No, you misunderstood: the last two commands should return a bool, and should be `True` in both cases. Also, note that by default Qt uses the system color dialog: what language does your os use?

Comment: My OS uses German. Translator Load and Install return False when I print the output.

Comment: Qt is normally shipped with a collection of standard languages, and German is certainly among them. Can you try to use one of the static functions of QColorDialog, which should use the native dialog? Also, what is the output of the `QLibraryInfo.location` function above? Do you have a file named `qt_de.qm`? If so, where is it located?

Comment: Output of QLibraryInfo.location is <built-in function location>

Comment: That is a function, it requires to be called with the argument you're using above.

Comment: Ok the funtion outputs a path in which the translation file (qt_de.qm) is existing.

Comment: @DavidK. Please show the actual output. What is the output of `print(QtCore.QLocale.system().name())` and `print(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))`?

Comment: I think the issue here is that `QLocale(QLocale.German).name()` may return `de_DE`, and this would then look for a file named `qt_de_DE.qm`, rather than `qt_de.qm`. Some built-in translation files use the full name and some don't, so I suppose you can also try `QtCore.QLocale.system().name().split('_')[0]` if loading the full name returns `False`.

Comment: You are right, the output is as follows:
Name: de_DE
Path: C:/Users/David/PycharmProjects/kundenkartei/venv/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations
But neither the split or hardcoding the filename works. What else can I try?

Comment: @DavidK. You must be doing something else wrong. If the file exists, `load` will certainly work (i.e. it *will* return `True`).

Comment: Load always returns False. This is my code, I really don't understand whats wrong:
`app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
qt_translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
translator = qt_translator.load("C:\\translations\\qt_de.qm")
install = app.installTranslator(qt_translator)
print(translator)
print(install)`

Comment: @DavidK. That must mean the file doesn't exist, or isn't readable, or isn't a valid translation file. You should use the file that's installed with the version of Qt you're using. The `load` function is smart enough to figure out the right file if you supply the right arguments. On my system, `translator.load('qt_de', QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location( QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))` returns `True`. If that returns `False` on your system, your Qt installation must be broken.

Comment: @DavidK. Your issue is strange. You're saying that your OS is in German; by default, Qt tries to use the *native* dialog from the OS, which means that even if QTranslator failed to load translation files, that would be irrelevant. I'm afraid that there could be something you're not aware or you're not telling us. Are you running the code in the Window Subsystem for Linux (I doubt it, since you're using Windows paths, but I've never used WSL)? Do you have a multi language setup for your OS (I'm not sure if Windows is capable of that)? What if you open the system color dialog in another program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to translate texts to German, you need to install a translator for German, not the system locale. Also the `QColorDialog()` shows the system color dialog if you don't specify the `DontUseNativeDialog` option. So do like this for "Qt for Python"(PySide2).

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])
trans = QTranslator()
trans.load('qt_de',
    QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
QCoreApplication.installTranslator(trans)

dlg = QColorDialog(None, options = QColorDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
dlg.exec()
```

Of course, you can use the name of the system locale instead of hard-coding the locale like this, as you did, if you want to use the system locale.

```
trans.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(),
    QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
```

For PyQt5, do like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])
trans = QTranslator()
trans.load('qt_de',
    QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
QCoreApplication.installTranslator(trans)

dlg = QColorDialog(None)
dlg.setOptions(QColorDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
dlg.exec()
```

But the current version(5.15.9) has is a bug that the `qtscript_*.qm` files are missing. So you should manually copy files from other Qt distribution. The following is an example of copying files from PySide2 in my Linux Anaconda environment.

```
$ cp ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/translations/qtscript*.qm ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations
```

For PyQt6, the above bug was fixed and you can do like this.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])
trans = QTranslator()
trans.load('qt_de',
    QLibraryInfo.path(QLibraryInfo.LibraryPath.TranslationsPath))
QCoreApplication.installTranslator(trans)

dlg = QColorDialog(None, options = QColorDialog.ColorDialogOption.DontUseNativeDialog)
dlg.exec()
```

Comment: That is exactly what has been discussed in the comments.

Comment: Pretty fast feedback! You mean the comment on not specifying the country code for the ```QTranslator.load()```? Then, it is incorrect. You CAN specify a country code.

Comment: I'm referring to the [last comment from ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75810595/change-language-in-qt-standarddialogs-qcolordialog/75851614?noredirect=1#comment133772279_75810595), which uses the same commands, and their previous one about to the issue of using `QLocale.name()`, which often uses the syntax `language_COUNTRY` (eg: `de_CH` for Switzerland), and can result in invalid paths as the default Qt translation file names are only based on language, no matter the country.

Comment: No, the ```Qtranslator.load()``` is smart enough so that it tries the translation file without the country code if it can't find one corresponding the country code.

Comment: But the point still remains, that was already discussed in comments, and the OP still got `False` anyway, so there's a problem either with their installation, or with something else.

Comment: I guess its because the OP didn't use the ```DontUseNativeDialog``` option. We will see.

Comment: That was my first doubt: by default Qt tries to use the native dialog and the OP said that their OS is in German indeed, which seems quite strange: even if QTranslator failed, that should have been irrelevant.

Comment: `DontUserNativeDialog` option didn't work either. The file is existing. How do I check if its a valid translation file? The app is executed in a PyCharm virtual environment, maybe thats a problem?

Comment: To the OP and @musicamante, it seems the mystery was solved at least for the non-native dialog. See the updated answer.

Comment: That did the trick, copied the missing translation files from QtDesignStudio translations directory. Thank you all!